# JSDocs: Documenting Node.js express routes

Tags: node.js, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am struggling documenting router.get calls with JSDocs. I am unable to get the documentation to display correctly on the page if I try to append it to my router call itself.

```
/**
 * Health check
 * @memberof health
 */
router.get('/happy', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ "status" : "OK" });
});
```

To resolve it, I made the functions have names.

```
router.get('/happy', happy);

/**
 * Health check
 * @memberof health
 */
function happy(req, res) {
    res.json({ "status" : "OK" });
}
```

This works, but I would really like to find a way to get the first method to work. Is there a way to document the first example? A keyword I can use?

Answer (score 30):

I do the following in my code.

```
/** Express router providing user related routes
 * @module routers/users
 * @requires express
 */

/**
 * express module
 * @const
 */
const express = require('express');

/**
 * Express router to mount user related functions on.
 * @type {object}
 * @const
 * @namespace usersRouter
 */
const router = express.Router();

/**
 * Route serving login form.
 * @name get/login
 * @function
 * @memberof module:routers/users~usersRouter
 * @inner
 * @param {string} path - Express path
 * @param {callback} middleware - Express middleware.
 */
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', {title: 'Login', message: 'You must login'});
});
```

And the output is: 
<s>[Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53190528/Screenshot%202017-01-07%2001.48.59.png)</s>
[image: Updated Screenshot - Module: routers/users]
[image: Namespace - usersRouter]

Comment: The screenshot URL returns 404 now :(

Comment: 20 hours spent my time looking for resolving the issue. Thank you so much, it works good.

Answer (score 2):

From a little bit of Googling, haven't actually tested.

```js
/**
 * Health check
 * @memberof health
 * @function
 * @name happy
 */
router.get('/happy', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ "status" : "OK" });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I try using this solution but it is resulting nothing, hmm. Can you kindly post the url where you find this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071897/how-to-document-anonymous-functions-closure-with-jsdoc-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

if you don't put "@module *moduleName*" on the top of the file, jsdoc will not reference the others comments on the page because they don't have a parent @module