# How do you document route params with JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, express, jsdoc

Currently working on some documentation for a javascript project and I would like to document the following:

```
/**
 * Express router to mount admin related functions on.
 * @namespace AdminRoutes
 */
const router = express.Router()
/**
 * Finds an admin based on the admin id stored in the session.
 * @function
 * @name get/:adminId
 * @memberof AdminRoutes
 * @param {string} adminId - The id of the admin to get.
 * @returns {Object} Returns an Admin object.
 */
router.get('/:adminId', async (request, response, next) => {
  try {
    return response.json(await Admin.findOne(request.session.user.id))
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error)
  }
})
```

This would work completely fine if this were a normal function, but when documenting as a route, the generate documentation shows up as a normal function named 'get' with adminId as a param. It is almost as if JSDoc is not respecting the @name field when naming the function. Is there a way around this or a proper way of documenting routes with params? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A little late, but check this, may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515805/6217195

Comment: @Rodrigo.A92 I like that solution a lot, thanks!

Comment: That link didn't help for me as it didn't contain an example with path parameters, as shown in OP's post.