# How to correctly use @callback for a simple function with the JSDoc Default Template?

Tags: javascript, templates, callback, comments, jsdoc

I try to use @callback in many way but I never obtain a documentation which use the way I expect when I use JSDoc API to generate documentation.

**1. The code I expected must be used**

With the following code in `callback-jsdoc-test.js`:

```
/**
 * The foo function for example.
 * function foo
 * @param  {Object}   bar  - The baz parrameters.
 * @param  {foo~next} next - What next after foo process ?
 */
function foo(bar, next) {
    if (bar === "baz") {
        return next(new Error("no baz allowed"));
    }

    bar += bar;

    /**
     * @callback foo~next
     * @param {(Object|null)}      err - return error object in case of error, else null.
     * @param {(Object|undefined)} bar - the bar value initialy passed and transformed, or nothing in case of error.
     */
    next(null, bar);
}
```

and the following JSDoc command:

```
jsdoc --private callback-jsdoc-test.js
```

I generate the following files:

```
out/
--index.html
--global.html
--callback-jsdoc-test.js.html
-- <directories...>
```

and in `global.html`

there are a `next   foo~next    What next after foo process ?` line with a link on `foo~next` text which go to `global.html#foo#~next` but this link point on nothing...

**2. Not use an inner path**

So, I try to not use `foo~next` but just `next`.

```
/**
 * The foo function for example.
 * function foo
 * @param  {Object}   bar  - The baz parrameters.
 * @param  {next} next - What next after foo process ?
 */
function foo(bar, next) {
    if (bar === "baz") {
        return next(new Error("no baz allowed"));
    }

    bar += bar;

    /**
     * @callback next
     * @param {(Object|null)}      err - return error object in case of error, else null.
     * @param {(Object|undefined)} bar - the bar value initialy passed and transformed, or nothing in case of error.
     */
    next(null, bar);
}
```

After generation of doc with default template:

There is effectively a type def created as said in documentation and the `global.html#next` works as expected but this solution does not fit to my needs because if I used an other `next` variable as parameter of an other callback,  two `next` variables will be enter in conflict. Also in this case `next` is `global` or this is not my intention because `next` is inner to `foo`. According to the documentation,  I must use many `nextOtherName` name to referenced all possible `next`...

** 3. Declare explicitly that is an inner function**

I also try to add the @inner keyword explicitly with the @memberOf declaration as following:

```
/**
 * The foo function for example.
 * function foo
 * @param  {Object}   bar  - The baz parrameters.
 * @param  {foo~next} next - What next after foo process ?
 */
function foo(bar, next) {
    if (bar === "baz") {
        return next(new Error("no baz allowed"));
    }

    bar += bar;

    /**
     * @callback next
     * @inner
     * @memberOf foo~
     * @param {(Object|null)}      err - return error object in case of error, else null.
     * @param {(Object|undefined)} bar - the bar value initialy passed and transformed, or nothing in case of error.
     */
    next(null, bar);
}
```

After generation of doc with default template:

There is always a `next` type def as global type def (not what I want) with the `next   foo~next    What next after foo process ?` but link point on nothing...

** 4. Add a namespace **

If I use the first code with @memberOf and @namespace

```
/**
 * The foo function for example.
 * @namespace foo
 * @param  {Object}   bar  - The baz parrameters.
 * @param  {foo~next} next - What next after foo process ?
 */
function foo(bar, next) {
    if (bar === "baz") {
        return next(new Error("no baz allowed"));
    }

    bar += bar;

    /**
     * @callback next
     * @memberOf foo~
     * @param {(Object|null)}      err - return error object in case of error, else null.
     * @param {(Object|undefined)} bar - the bar value initialy passed and transformed, or nothing in case of error.
     */
    next(null, bar);
}
```

After generation of doc with default template:

The `global.htm` is now `foo.htm` and type def is attached to `foo.htm` but because of @namespace, the function is now refferenced as a namespace and not as a function so the function description with the `foo~next` link does not appear... logical, and it's not what I want.

** 5. Use class in place of namespace **

If I use the previous code with @memberOf and @class

```
/**
 * The foo function for example.
 * @class foo
 * @param  {Object}   bar  - The baz parrameters.
 * @param  {foo~next} next - What next after foo process ?
 */
function foo(bar, next) {
    if (bar === "baz") {
        return next(new Error("no baz allowed"));
    }

    bar += bar;

    /**
     * @callback next
     * @memberOf foo~
     * @param {(Object|null)}      err - return error object in case of error, else null.
     * @param {(Object|undefined)} bar - the bar value initialy passed and transformed, or nothing in case of error.
     */
    next(null, bar);
}
```

After generation of doc with default template:

There are effectively the function description AND a good link to callback type def but in this case I declare my simple function as a Class and it's absolutly not the case (no usage of new, not a constructor, etc.) so it's still not the good way.

** 6. Use the method keyword**

I decided after all this to use the @method keyword and it's the same issue that first example. Moreover, @method is useful for function into a @class, not global function...

**So...**

What is the correct way to comment a callback of simple function as a specific type def and not global?

Comment: There are no one can have an advice for this question ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to document anonymous functions (closure) with jsdoc-toolkit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071897/how-to-document-anonymous-functions-closure-with-jsdoc-toolkit)